Order of group of isometries of a quadratic form in characteristic $2$
Let $V$ be an even dimensional vector space over the finite field $\mathbb{F}_\ell$ where $\ell$ is even, and set $n=\dim_{\mathbb{F}_\ell}(V)$. Let $q:V\to \mathbb{F}_\ell$ be a quadratic form, and let
$$
b:V\times V\to \mathbb{F}_\ell, \quad (x,y)\mapsto q(x+y)-q(x)-q(y)
$$
be the associated (symmetric) bilinear form on $V$. Note that $b(x,x)=2q(x)=0$ for all $x$, so that $(V,b)$ is a symplectic space.
We assume that
$$
\mathrm{rad}(b) = \{x\in V \; | \; b(x,y)=0 \text{ for all } y\in V\}
$$
is the zero set. I am interested in compute the order of the group $O(q)$ of linear isometries of the quadratic space $(V,q)$, that is
$$
O(q) = \{g\in \mathrm{GL}(V) \; | \; q(gx)=q(x) \text{ for all } x\in V \}.
$$
We can also consider the group of linear isometries $O(b)$ of the bilinear form $b$,
$$
O(b) = \{g\in \mathrm{GL}(V) \; | \; b(gx,gy)=b(x,y) \text{ for all } x,y\in V \}.
$$
It is easy to see that $O(q)\leq O(b)$, and I was able to compute the order $|O(b)|$ of the group $O(b)$, giving
$$
|O(b)| = \ell^{n^2/4}\prod_{j=1}^{n/2}(\ell^{2j}-1). \tag{1}\label{eq1}
$$
Now, I am unable to compute the order of the group $O(q)$. In this book, Proposition 2.5.5 states, without proof, that the order of $Q(q)$ must be
$$
|O(q)| = 2\ell^{n(n-2)/4}(\ell^{n/2}-1)\prod_{j=1}^{n/2-1}(\ell^{2j}-1). \tag{2}\label{eq2}
$$
At the end of this post I'm adding my proof of \eqref{eq1}. I want to know if this proof can be adapted to compute $|O(q)|$ or if, for example, we can compute directly the index of $O(q)$ in $O(b)$, in order to derive from it the value of $|O(q)|$. Any help with the proof itself or with a reference where I can find this computation made explicitly will be appreciated.
ADDED:
To be precise, the precise statement in the mentioned book is a bit more complex. I'll state the part corresponding to the even dimensional case.
First of all, Proposition 2.5.3 in this book states that if $\dim V=n=2m$ is even, then the following dichotomy occurs:

There is a basis $(e_1,\dots,e_m,f_1,\dots,f_m)$ of $V$ that is $q$-symplectic, that is,
$$
q(e_i)=q(f_i)=0, \quad b(e_i,f_j)=\delta_{ij}\quad i,j=1,\dots,m.
$$
There is a basis $(e_1,\dots,e_{m-1},f_1,\dots,f_{m-1},x,y)$ and an element $a\in \mathbb{F}_\ell$ such that the polynomial $x^2+x+a$ is irreducible over $\mathbb{F}_\ell$, and
$$
q(x)=1, \quad q(y)=a, \quad b(x,y)=1, \quad b(x,e_i)=b(y,e_i)=0, \quad i=1,\dots,m-1
$$
$$
q(e_i)=q(f_i)=0, \quad b(e_i,f_j)=\delta_{ij}\quad i,j=1,\dots,m-1.
$$

I made a mistake by (I don't know why) assuming that the hypothesis $\mathrm{rad}(b)=0$ implied the existence of a basis of the type 1, and that's why I didn't mentioned it before. Thanks to Captain Lama for making me notice this!
Now, let $\epsilon=1$ if case 1 holds, and $\epsilon=-1$ if case 2 is fulfilled. Then the precise statement of Proposition 2.5.5 (again, just the even dimensional case) is
$$
|O(q)| =  2\ell^{n(n-2)/4}(\ell^{n/2}-\epsilon)\prod_{j=1}^{n/2-1}(\ell^{2j}-1).
$$
Computation of $|O(b)|$.
It is easy to see that $O(b)$ is in bijection with the set of symplectic bases of $(V,b)$, that is, (ordered) bases of the form $(e_1,\dots,e_{n/2},f_1,\dots,f_{n/2})$ such that
$$
b(e_i,f_j) = \delta_{ij}, \quad b(e_i,e_j)=b(f_i,f_j)=0, \quad i,j=1,\dots,n/2.
$$
Choose any nonzero vector $e_1\in V\setminus\{0\}$, there are $\ell^n-1$ possible choices of $e_1$. Now, for each $a\in\mathbb{F}_\ell$ set
$$
V(e_1,a) = \{x\in V \; | \; b(e_1,x)=a\}.
$$
Note that $e_1\in V(e_1,0)$, that the sets $V(e_1,a)$, that ($a\in\mathbb{F}_\ell$) are pairwise disjoint, and that if $a\neq 0$, then the map
$$
V(e_1,1)\to V(e_1,a), \quad x\mapsto ax
$$
is a bijection. Moreover, as $\mathrm{rad}(b)=0$, there exists $x\in V$ with $b(e_1,x)\neq 0$, and consequently $V(e_1,a)\neq 0$ for all $a\neq 0$. Choose any element $x_1\in V(e_1,1)$, then the map
$$
V(e_1,0)\to V(e_1,1), \quad x\mapsto x+x_1
$$
is a bijection with inverse $x\mapsto x-x_1$. Thus all the sets $V(e_1,a)$ have the same cardinality as $a$ runs over $\mathbb{F}_\ell$ and since they clearly form a partition of $V$, we deduce that
$$
|V(e_1,a)|=|V|/\ell = \ell^{n-1}, \quad a\in\mathbb{F}_\ell.
$$
Now, $e_2$ must be an element of $V(e_1,1)$ so there are $q^{n-1}$ choices for $e_2$. So we have a total of
$$
(\ell^n-1)\ell^{n-1}
$$
choices for the pair $(e_1,e_2)$. Now, set
$$
V' = \{x\in V \; | \; b(x,e_1)=b(x,e_2)=0\}.
$$
Then it is easy to see that $V'$ is an $n-2$ dimensional subspace of $V$, and recursively we deduce that
$$
|O(b)| = \prod_{j=1}^{n/2}(\ell^{2j}-1)\ell^{2j-1} = \ell^{n^2/4}\prod_{j=1}^{n/2}(\ell^{2j}-1),
$$
which proves \eqref{eq1}.

The two formulas you give seem to indicate that $[O(b):O(q)]=\ell^m(\ell^m+1)/2$ where $n=2m$, but for $n=2$ I think I find that the correct answer is $\ell^m(\ell^m+1)/2$ when the Arf invariant of $q$ is trivial, and $\ell^m(\ell^m-1)/2$ when it's non-trivial. I'm not 100% sure, and I can't show the whole reasoning in the comments, but just to be sure, is there no hypothesis on the Arf invariant in the book you quote?

Ok I'm pretty sure I can prove that in general the index is $\ell^m(\ell^m\pm 1)/2$ with a $+1$ when the Arf invariant of $q$ is trivial, and a $-1$ otherwise. I'll write an answer later, but you should check the book, because if it does not have such a dichotomy it might be incorrect (or I made a mistake, also possible).

@CaptainLama the book does not mention anything about the Arf invariant (and I never heard of it until now). Nevertheless, I posted only a small part of the theorem regarding the value of the order of the group. The book states that the order of the group depends on three possibilities according to the existence of a basis of $V$ with certain properties. It is too complicated for a comment, but I can add it to the post if you wish. Thanks!

Independently of what I personally wish, your book is telling you that the formula depends on some condition, so I find it strange not to mention it in your question, as it means you are aware that the formula you wrote is just not correct in some cases. Probably the condition on the basis amounts to computing the Arf invariant (which is the analogue of the discriminant in the characteristic $2$ case, and can also just be called the discriminant). I don't know what the third case might be, maybe when the dimension is odd?

@CaptainLama Yes, my bad! I wrongly believed that the condition on the basis was fulfilled under the assumption that $\mathrm{rad}(b)=0$, that's why I didn't mentioned it in my post. And yes, the third case is when the space is odd dimensional.

Let $Q(V)$ be the space of nondegenerate quadratic forms $V\to K$ (for now let us just assume that $K$ has characteristic $2$), and $B(V)$ be the space of bilinear forms $V\times V\to K$, with $A(V)\subset B(V)$ the subspace of alternating bilinear forms. Then $GL(V)$ acts naturally on $Q(V)$ and on $B(V)$, and stabilizes $A(V)$. The orbit of a given quadratic form $q$ (resp. bilinear form $b$) is by definition the set of quadratic (resp. bilinear) forms on $V$ that are isometric to $q$ (resp. $b$), and by definition $O(q)$ (resp. $O(b)$) is the stabilizer of $q$ (resp. $b$).
The canonical map $Q(V)\to A(V)$ given by $q\mapsto b_q$ (with $b_q(x,y)=q(x+y)-q(x)+q(y)$ measuring the default of additivity of $q$) is $GL(V)$-equivariant, which is a fancy way to show that $O(q)$ is a subgroup of $O(b_q)$.
There is a single orbit in $A(V)$: all alternating bilinear forms are isometric, as you used in your proof, because they all have a symplectic basis $(e_1,f_1,\dots,e_m,f_m)$ (where $n=2m$).
On the other hand, not all quadratic forms are isometric. Given any symplectic basis $(e_1,f_1,\dots,e_m,f_m)$ of $b_q$, if we write $a_i=q(e_i)$ and $b_i=q(f_i)$, then $q$ is entirely determined (as a function, not just its isometry class) by the $a_i$ and $b_i$ through
$$q(\sum_i x_ie_i+y_if_i) = \sum_i ax_i^2+x_iy_i + b_iy_i^2.$$
The form $(x,y)\mapsto ax^2+xy+by^2$ is often denoted by $[a,b]$, and we saw that any even-dimensional quadratic form is isometric to an orthogonal sum of such binary forms.
Recall the Artin-Schreier map $\wp: K\to K$ given by $\wp(x)=x^2+x$ (it is an additive group morphism). Artin-Schreier theory tells us that quadratic étale $K$-algebras are of the form $K(\wp^{-1}(a))$ for some $a\in K$ (it is a separable quadratic field extension when $a\not\in \wp(K)$, and is isomorphic to $K\times K$ when $a\in \wp(K)$), and that gives a bijection from the set of isomorphism classes of quadratic étale $K$-algebras and the (additive) group $K/\wp(K)$. In particular, if $K$ is finite, $[K:\wp(K)]=2$ (there is only one quadratic extension, which is of course separable since $K$ is perfect).
To each $q\in Q(V)$ we can assign an element $\delta(q)\in K/\wp(K)$, called its Arf invariant. Canonically, the center of the Clifford algebra $Cl(V,q)$ is a quadratic étale $K$-algebra, and $\delta(q)$ is the corresponding class by Artin-Schreier theory. Concretely, given a basis $(e_1,\dots,f_m)$ as above, we have
$$ \delta(q) = a_1b_1+\dots +a_mb_m \in K/\wp(K).$$
This is because $\delta([a,b])=ab$ by direct computation, and $\delta(q\perp q')=\delta(q)+\delta(q')$. Now a crucial theorem of Arf (and Dickson) is that when $K$ is perfect, $\delta(q)$ completely determines the isometry class of $q$. So for instance $q$ is isometric to $[0,0]\perp\dots\perp [0,0]\perp [1,a]$ where $a\in K$ is a representative of $\delta(q)$. In particular, if $K$ is finite there are only two isometry classes of nondegenerate quadratic forms in each even dimension.
Let us come back to the index $[O(b_q):O(q)]$, with $K=\mathbb{F}_\ell$. By general facts about group actions, $O(b_q)/O(q)$ is in bijection with the set of $q'\in Q(V)$ such that $b_{q'}=b_q$ and $q$ and $q'$ are isometric (the fiber of the $GL(V)$-orbit of $q$ above $b_q$). The fact that $b_q=b_{q'}$ exactly means that $(e_1,\dots,f_m)$ is also a symplectic basis for $q'$, and therefore $q'$ is entirely characterized by the values $q'(e_i)$ and $q'(f_i)$ (we get simultaneously $q=[a_1,b_1]\perp\dots\perp [a_m,b_m]$ and $q'=[a'_1,b'_1]\perp\dots\perp [a'_m,b'_m]$ using the same basis). So there are $\ell^n$ quadratic forms $q'$ such that $b_q=b_{q'}$. But only those with the same Arf invariant as $q$ are isometric to $q$. Therefore:
$$ [O(b_q):O(q)] = |\{ (a_1,b_1,\dots,a_m,b_m)\in K^n\,|\, \sum a_ib_i = \delta(q)\in K/\wp(K)\}|.$$
Let us write $I_m\subset K^n$ for the subset in the above formula. We want to show that
$$ |I_m| = \frac{\ell^m(\ell^m+\varepsilon)}{2} $$
where $\varepsilon=1$ when $\delta(q)$ is trivial, and $\varepsilon = -1$ otherwise (so the index is different for the two isometry classes of quadratic forms). We show this by induction. Note that even if we might not want to think too much about whether what we're doing with quadratic forms works when $m=0$, at least $I_0$ is perfectly well-defined, and equals $K^0$ when $\delta(q)$ is trivial (as the empty sum is $0\in \wp(K)$), and is empty otherwise. So
$$|I_0| = \left\{ \begin{array}{ll} 1 & \text{if } \delta(q)=0 \\
0 & \text{otherwise.} \end{array} \right. $$
Let $(a_1,\dots,b_m)\in K^n$, with $m\geqslant 1$. If $a_m=0$, then $(a_1,\dots,b_m)\in I_m$ if and only if $(a_1,\dots,b_{m-1})\in I_{m-1}$, independently of $b_m$. If $a_m\neq 0$, then $b\mapsto a_mb+\sum_{i<m}a_ib_i$ is a bijection $K\to K$, so there are $|\wp(K)|=\ell/2$ values of $b_m$ such that $(a_1,\dots,b_m)\in I_m$ for each choice of $a_1,\dots,b_{m-1}$. In total, this proves the relation
$$ |I_m| = \ell|I_{m-1}| + \ell^{2(m-1)}(\ell-1)\frac{\ell}{2}. $$
Now it just remains to check that the formula we gave satisfies the induction formula, with the dichotomy at $m=0$ depending on $\delta(q)$. I'll leave that as an easy exercise.

Thank you! I'm going to take a look at your answer :) Also, I'm going to add some details to the question to make it precise the dichotomy about the dimension.
